# Sharing image folder between two domains cakephp

Tags: cakephp, dns, sharing, subdomain

I have a website and a sub-domain that allows users to upload images to their account, the two domains are cakephp applications that share the same CakeLib but different apps dir. I want to be able to access images uploaded from either domains from the other one (e.g. if a user goes on the sub-domain and uploads an image, I should be able to access the same image from the parent domain and vise-versal).

Please note, accessing this images is done strictly in the views. I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->Html->image('http://subdomain.example.com/image.png');
```

Something like the above? :o, you could extend your helper as well:

```
class MyAppHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $helpers = array('Html');

    public function subdImage($path) {
        return $this->Html->image('http://subdomain.example.com/' . $path);
    }
}
```

and call it from your view like:

```
$this->MyApp->subdImage('image.png');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to avoid making a cross-domain call for the images because that will take considerable longer that if I was accessing the images locally. Thats why I didn't use this tactic in the 1st place

Comment: Are you sure it would take longer? They are both being served from the same host by the same client.

Comment: @sfagade what do you mean slower? :o, browsers can load different images in parallel if they are hosted from two different domains (subdomain are treated differently), if anything, this should make your app faster. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

`The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel.`

Comment: Thanks, thats all I need to know. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help :), you can thank me by clicking the hollow "V" sign besides my answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Simply [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) the folder. I would make my upload path configurable and point it to /home/www-data/images for example and symlink it to both apps like /var/www/app1/webroot/img and /var/www/app2/webroot/img. No code needed at all. Symlinking works also on windows.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you can create symlink on a cpanel shared hosting. Can you